# Getting error when comapre the existing screen shot with real time application in cypress

Tags: cypress, screenshot

If I do compare the screen shot with the real time application then it's getting failed. What would be best approach and ****how to compare the screen shot in Cypress****

Output: getting error log on cypress for

[image]

installed dependency for comparing the screen shot

```bash
npm install --save-dev cypress-image-snapshot @types/cypress-image-snapshot
```

```js
// code on commond.js file.
const compareSnapshotCommand = require('cypress-image-diff-js/dist/command')
compareSnapshotCommand();

 // code on cypress.config.json 
 const getCompareSnapshotsPlugin = require('cypress-image-diff-js/dist/plugin')
      getCompareSnapshotsPlugin(on, config)

// .js test scenario on test file 
describe('compare the homepage screen shot with the application homepage', () => {
    it('should compare the homepage', () => {
        cy.visit("/");
        cy.compareSnapshot('fixtures/healthcaresuccess-page.png', 0.001);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to alter your [image difference threshold](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/cypress-image-snapshot#options). Right now it is set to 0.001. You'll need to either set a new base reference image or change the option to allow for more difference before failing the test.

In your `<rootDir>/cypress/support/commands.js`, you can alter the option

```js
addMatchImageSnapshotCommand({
  // alter to your choosing
  failureThreshold: 0.05, // threshold for entire image
});
```